# jquery page load to appear only when form is filled

Tags: jquery

A tiny issue that I am experiencing. I am by no means a programmer so I am finding hard to get my head around this.

I have a form with some required field. I want that when the user has filled the form, while it is being submitted, for them to get a 'Please wait while processing screen'. And that's fine, I am able to get get BUT if the user fails to fill a required field, that please wait while it's loading div still appears and cannot be back to fill the form.

```
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$('#loading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

This is the all the code I am using to bring up the please wait while loading div. So how can I make it trigger only when the form is actually being submitted and not appear if required fields are not filled.

Thanks
Saj

Comment: Can you post HTML code? Is this really the only JavaScript you are using?

Comment: This question is missing a lot of important details (like the rest of your code for one thing!) but from what I can gather, you are actually submitting the form.  When the form submits and the page loads again, that 'load' event fires and you show the loading message.  Do I have it right?  If that's so, then the paradigm shift you need to make is to not submit the form unless there are no validation errors and to show the loading message only when there are no errors.